# Different result precision between different gpus with the same program

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a problem with my program. I ran my program a few times on my GTX980 and I got the same results. But when program runs on P4, the accuracy of the results obtained from each run is not the same. All calculations in the program only dnn.
The result like:

```
output1:2.70637 -0.59397  -2.39845 -1.00066 -0.27046
output2:2.70637 -0.593971 -2.39845 -1.00066 -0.270459
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting @Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format the output depending on your output precision. That is one of the options to get rid of the extra decimal places. If you would like to perform the calculations with different precision, check Nvidia's page on mixed precision programming. https://devblogs.nvidia.com/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/